# thrown TargetInvocationException after calling sentiment API

Tags: silverlight, wcf, targetinvocationexception

**We are developing Silverlight  web application to display the tweets on the map and analyse the tweets by using sentiment API. we used sentiment API without problems for 3 or 4 weeks. Then, we sometimes faced  TargetInvocationException after calling sentiment API**

Now, we face TargetInvocationException after calling sentiment API more and more.

XDocument newdoc = XDocument.Parse(en.Result);

en.Result become null and

the exception is shown :

System.Reflection.TargetInvocatinException : An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. Check InnerExcepton for exception details. --->
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound ---> System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult ayncResult)
at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_DisplalyClass4.b__1(Object sendState)
---End of inner exception stack trace
at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult ayncResult)
at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
---End of inner exception stack trace
at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
at System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEvent Args.get_Result()
at SilverlightApplication1.MainPage.<>c_DisplayClass1a.<>c_DisplayClass23.b__16(Object ss, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs en)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exception when I had a data contract class which had a property of type Enum. Then I decorated the DataContract with [KnownType (typeof(MyEnum))]. I did not see this exception after that.